# Center Text QML type based on the dot of a decimal number

Tags: qt, text, qml, center

I've got a simple `Text` `QML` type:

```
Item {
    anchors.fill: parent

    Text {
        id: centerText
        text: "6.9"
        anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
        y: 570
    }
}
```

Currently, the `Text` will be centered based on the whole length of the string. 
But I would like to center the `Text` based on the dot character.

I was thinking of splitting the actual `Text` in three parts: the round part, the dot and the decimal part. However I don't think I could split the `float` variable to only get the decimal part.

Is there another way more convenient and adapted to `QML`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quick example how you can achieve that. The "dummy" hidden text is used to measure how wide the integer part of the number is, obtained by using `Math.floor()`. Then you simply position it so that the decimal point is always in the center of the parent object regardless of what the number is.

```
 Column {
    x: 100
    y: 200
    spacing: 5
    Slider {
      id: sl
      width: 400
      minimumValue: 0
      maximumValue: 100
    }
    Rectangle {
      width: 400
      height: 100
      Text {
        x: parent.width * .5 - dummy.width
        y: parent.height * .5 - height * .5
        text: sl.value
        Text {
          id: dummy
          text: Math.floor(sl.value)
          visible: false
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

[image]

BTW, when you have `anchors.fill: parent` then `anchors.bottom: parent.bottom` is redundant.

Comment: Might be possible to use a FontMetrics element instead of the hidden dummy text, http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-fontmetrics.html

Comment: @KevinKrammer - that's a good idea, I haven't noticed FontMetric even though it is available since 5.4. Most of my code base is still QtQuick 2.5.

Answer (score 2):

**EDIT: in the end I used [ddriver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/991484/ddriver)'s solution. If you are using custom fonts, don't forget to include its options in the dummy `Text` as well!**

<s>I haven't been able to reproduce [ddriver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/991484/ddriver)'s solution.</s> I came up with my own. I searched how to get the decimal part of a float value in JavaScript and found this:

```
(4.89 + "").split(".")[1]; => 89
```

This is more convenient than the `C++` [modf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/modf/) function as it is not returning the "0." part.

Thanks to this, I just had to create three `Text` `QML` types:

```
// Center horizontally number based on the dot
Text {
    id: testValueRoundPart
    anchors.right: testSpeedDot.left
    y: 570
    text:  (6.9 + "").split(".")[0]
}

Text {
    id: testSpeedDot
    y: 570
    text:  "."
    anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter
}

Text {
    id: testSpeedValueDecimalPart
    y: 570
    anchors.left: testSpeedDot.right
    text: (6.9 + "").split(".")[1];
}
```

I've been using this with custom fonts (Sans-Guilt and Universalis; I don't think these are Monospace fonts) and it worked.
It may not be the most optimized solution but it fits my needs.

Comment: In my example, the value comes from the slider, just for the sake of interactivity. Just remove the column, slider, and replace the rectangle with a regular Item as in your OP. That solution would be a little more efficient than yours - only 2 text elements rather than 3 and less anchoring. The concept is simple - put the text in the center of the parent minus the width of the integer part so that the dot gets in the middle.

Comment: I've been able to make it work this time by removing the `font.family` and the `font.pixelSize` of my `Text`. However, if I use one of the fonts I've quoted in my answer, it doesn't work.

I guess we need to take in account the thickness of the custom font to make it work.

Comment: Hmmm, it shouldn't matter really, as long as both text elements are using the same font and style. I will see how it handles with custom fonts.

Comment: No, nevermind! It's my fault. I had forgotten to add my font options in my dummy `Text`... I'll amend my answer and tick yours.

Comment: Yeah that's what I thought ;)

Answer (score 0):

You might have to use something like 0-based padding in order to achieve the desired alignment -- or find a monospaced font and then use spaces instead of 0s

Either way -- this could be a solution:

```js
import QtQuick 2.0


Item {
      height: 480
      width: 320
      /* list of float strings to pad */
      property var myFloats: ["6.9", "36.21", "4.632", "4225.2", "12.0"]
   

       /*  apply  zero-based padding to the strings on startup
           and output to the console */
      Component.onCompleted: {
           console.log(pad_floats());
      }

   
  /* function takes each decimal,and each integer separated by the .
      and figures out the length of the longest one, then uses
      a padding algorithm to add 0s to the start of the integers
      and 0s to the back of decimals and returns an array */
      function pad_floats() {
          var longest_int = 0;
          var longest_float = 0;
          var newFloats = [];
          for (var i = 0; i < myFloats.length; i++) {
              var tmp_float = myFloats[i];
              var tmp_int = tmp_float.split(".")[0]; // left side
              var tmp_dec = tmp_float.split(".")[1]; // right side

              /* check if either number is more digits than our longest one */
              if (tmp_int.length > longest_int) {
                    longest_int = tmp_int.length;
              }
              if (tmp_dec.length > longest_float) {
                    longest_float = tmp_dec.length;
              }

          }

          for (var u = 0; u < myFloats.length; u++) {
              var tmp_float = myFloats[u];
              var tmp_int = tmp_float.split(".")[0]; // left side of .
              var tmp_dec = tmp_float.split(".")[1]; // right side of .

              /* pad the two numbers */
              var new_int = pad(parseInt(tmp_int), longest_int, "0"); 
              var new_dec = pad(parseInt(tmp_dec), 0 - longest_float, "0");

              /* combine the new numbers back into one */
              var new_float = new_int + "." + new_dec;

              /* add to our array  to return */
              newFloats.push(new_float);

        }
        return newFloats;


  }

  function pad(n, width, z) {
       z = z || '0';
       n = n + '';
       return n.length >= width ? n : new Array(width - n.length + 1).join(z) + n;
  }

   /*   Heres the ListView to show the actual list of floats */
  ListView {
       width: 320
       height: 480
       anchors.fill: parent
       anchors.left: parent.left
       model: pad_floats()  // our returned array from before
       delegate: listDelegate  // pointer to the Component below


  }

  Component {
      id: listDelegate
      Text {
          text: modelData
          font.pointSize: 11
          verticalAlignment: Text.AlignVCenter
          horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
      }
  }
```

Result from running this operation is a ListView with the following entries:

```
0006.9
0036.21
0004.632
4225.2
0012.0
```

And thats it...  Like I said at the top of the answer -- in order to create the desired result  of having just the numbers with no extra 0s , you would have to use a font which has the same space amount for each character, including the (space) character.

These are typically called Monotype or Monospace fonts.

Usually those fonts will have the word "Mono" connected with their names to make finding them easier.

Once you've found a good monotype font,  replace the following code in the pad_floats() function:

Old code

```
      var new_int = pad(parseInt(tmp_int), longest_int, "0");
      var new_dec = pad(parseInt(tmp_dec), 0 - longest_float, "0");
```

New code

```
      var new_int = pad(parseInt(tmp_int), longest_int, " ");
      var new_dec = pad(parseInt(tmp_dec), 0 - longest_float, " ");
```

Notice how I changed the last "0" parameter to a " "?  That last string is the padding string, so you could put anything in there and it would fill in with that string.

Enjoy.

Comment: I realize that this is not the "most efficient" way to do this persay -- but I wrote out a more "verbose" way of doing it rather than  combining a bunch of operations into one big blob

Comment: It doesn't work without monospace fonts, and monospace fonts are rarely used in UI design, they are text console type of fonts used manly for coding. With the lack of access to font metrics from QML, using a hidden text element to measure the width is the only possible solution that works in every case.

Comment: Yeah - it seems like a more efficient way of handling it would be to use the hidden text box anyways -- running JS functions in QML doesn't ever seem to work out